# Am I getting the correct normal?

Tags: normals, normal-map

I am trying to create a normal map for the hair but I feel that normal map is getting generated wrongly.
I used hair particles and converted them to mesh. Then I applied screw modifier then I applied solidify.
But the results are not what I expect. Does UV of the high poly object has any importance here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What result are you expecting and how does the current one deviate from it?

Comment: @RobertGützkow Should be it having an even distribution of colours?  But for this one, it seems to like a gradient from right to left?

Comment: If the hair makes an arc (viewed from the top) this would be correct.

Comment: @RobertGützkow if it arc both arc ends should be having same color right?

Comment: The color encodes the direction of the normal at that specific pixel. They should only have the same color if they point in the same direction.